# setprecision without iomanip

Tags: c++

I want to compile a C++ application and I must not use

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Is there any alternative way to do that?

Info: I need the setprecision to be 5

Comment: Why was it tagged with c, jquery & php?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you have the ability to use

```
cout.precision(5);
```

This does not require

```
#include <iomanip>
```

**Note:** This will set precision for the whole document.

**Example:**

```
cout.precision(5);
cout << f;
```

Comment: The `precision()` setting is always sticky. The only standard formatting setting which isn't sticky is `width()`.

Comment: And I find it a good convention to only use manipulators for non-sticky settings (or manipulators which reset the settings at the end of the full expression).  But I seem to be alone in this.  (Of course, in real code, you'll almost never use a standard manipulator other than `std::setw`, and you can arrange for your home build manipulators to reset the state at the end of the full expression.)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `precision()` directly on the stream, e.g.:

```
std::cout.precision(5);
```

Comment: I am using "using namespace std".

Comment: So? I'm working on large pieces of software and I found that qualifying names with their respective namespace is helpful to avoid ambiguities. Also, it wasn't visible from the question that a using directive is being used (which I consider to be bad practise in most cases).

Comment: @Amden: You're free to take away the `std::` if you don't need it in your own code; similarly, if you made a reference to `std::cout` you can use that (`std::ostream& amden = std::cout; amden.precision(5);`). But it's right that the full and correct original line of code be presented here.